# How to use shadowJar to publish a multi-module Android library to Maven as one repository?

Tags: android, maven, shadowjar

I'm working on an Android library which has many modules and once core module that gets published to Maven. The problem is that the core module still depends on the submodules after it's published, and this doesn't seem to work. I've heard that the way to fix this is by creating a fat jar/shadow jar using the [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) library. I know this has been asked before, but does anyone know how to configure an android library to include its submodules, and publish this under one repository rather than publishing each module as its own maven repository?